# Bootstrap messing/overlapping up on certain devices

Tags: html, ios, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm no bootstrap/html/css expert, and I recently started messing around with some templates/codes and started doing a website for my brother in law.

I'm pretty happy with the results, for a first timer and 4 days later I can say that I achieved what I wanted. However, the mobile version don't seem to work properly on every browser/resolution. I don't know what I did wrong. I've tried on my Xperia ZL on Chrome and everything looks fine. On the iPhone though, it looks like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/9iZhG.png. (website: http://www.maconneriesdi.com)

As you can see, the "about" section is overlapping the "work" section on the iPhone(almost 720p). I've tried on my Xperia S (720p) and had the same problem. Tried with different browsers. On the iPad and Xperia ZL(1080p) the website looked fine. When I resize my window on my computer (1400x900) to the minimum, I also don't have that problem on every browser I tested. Also, the fonts I used on the website don't work on mobile.

here is my code

```
<head>
  <title>Maçonnerie SDI</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/grayscale.css">
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400italic,700italic,400,700&subset=cyrillic,cyrillic-ext,latin,greek-ext,greek,latin-ext,vietnamese' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

</head>
```

And here goes the "about" section

```
<!--ABOUT SECTION-->
<div class="row">
<section id="about" class="container content-section text-center">
    <div class="row">
        <h1 class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2 text-uppercase"><strong>À propos de nous</strong></h1>
        <div class="row">
            <p class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2 lead">Dans une industrie de plus en plus compétitive telle que la maçonnerie, rares sont ceux qui se démarquent.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <p class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2 lead">Constamment à la recherche de la perfection en matière de rapidité, d'efficacité et d'exactitude, Maçonnerie SDI allie expérience et énergie pour mener à terme tous ses projets indépendamment de ses envergures.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <p class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2 lead">Forte de son ambition et de sa volonté, elle s'impose déjà comme un des leaders de sa catégorie en maçonnerie au Québec.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
</div>

<!--WORK SECTION-->
<div id="work" class="row">
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="container">
            <h2 class="text-uppercase text-center">Réalisations</h2>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm center-block" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#gallery">Voir projets</button>
        </div><!--div container-->
    </div><!--div collape-->
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    font-family: Open Sans,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    color: #000;
    background-color: #fff;
}

html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have hard-coded your `about` ID's height to 400px. This is fine on bigger screens but when the text wraps on smaller screens it's pushing the size bigger. Try changing the `#about` height to 550px which worked for me when I just tested your live site link on iPhone 4S (a really small device) under responsive design mode.

New code should look like

```
#about {padding-top:100px;height:550px;color: #000; background-color: #fff;}
```

Also as a general rule it's a bad idea to have style rules in the HTML document. It just ends up getting messy and means you can't reuse those rules elsewhere. Always create a css file and store all the style rules there and then call that file in the header.

EDIT:

A better solution is as H. Allen suggests removing the height parameters completely but if you want to keep them that's the change you need to make.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the height properties.  Bootstrap takes care of that for you.

Answer (score 0):

thanks very much guys! I was thinking I codded something wrong in the about section! never thought it could be it! thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem while building a website with Bootstrap. Try removing the height properties in your CSS. Since the divs resize responsively with Bootstrap, it doesn't like it when specific heights are set.

Hope this helps!